# Python: how to show timestamp other than datetime function

Tags: python

I get below dictionary data from aws. In python, how can I get it show timestamp instead of datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 26, 10, 57, 19, 215000, tzinfo=tzlocal()) there?

Thanks,

> {
> "ConfigRuleName": "required-tags",
> "OrderingTimestamp": datetime.datetime(
> 2020, 10, 26, 10, 57, 19, 215000, tzinfo=tzlocal()
> ),
> "ResourceId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:553763988947:stack/es-edge-security-headers-kells/f1924880-8311-11ea-9a26-0af77bd56d08",
> "ResourceType": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack", }

Comment: `datetime.datetime` objects have a `strftime` function. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime). There are also other methods for displaying the date, depending on what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is that you are looking for..
Isn't it already a datetime object ?

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.tz import *
d=datetime(2020, 10, 26, 10, 57, 19, 215000, tzinfo=tzlocal())
print(d.timestamp())
print(str(d))
```

Output :

```
1603690039.215
2020-10-26 10:57:19.215000+05:30
```

Comment: Thanks, Johnson
What I want to do is to show the response like:
{ "ConfigRuleName": "required-tags", "OrderingTimestamp": "2020-10-26 10:57:19.215000+05:30", "ResourceId": "arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:553763988947:stack/es-edge-security-headers-kells/f1924880-8311-11ea-9a26-0af77bd56d08", "ResourceType": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack", }

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the normal definition of a timestamp you can just call the datetime timestamp function. This will give you a float representing seconds from the epoch (this is the norm for Python in C it would be an int).

So if you put in the line:

```
ThatDictionary["OrderingTimeStamp"] = ThatDictionary["OrderingTimeStamp"].timestamp()
```

You'll permanently convert that value in the dictionary to a timestamp. You can convert it back if you want later or create a copy of the dict and do that to print it out or just run the timestamp() method on that element whenever you use it.